# Render component depend on state or block/pass dispatching in function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have 2 approaches.

I can :

```
{isBtnEnabled ? (
        <button onClick={this.props.someDispatchedAction} />
      ) : (
        <button/>
)}
```

Or maybe should I use :

```
someCoolName = () => {
  if(isBtnEnabled)
    this.props.someDispatchedAction();
}

...

<button onClick={this.someCoolName}>
```

Which solution is better and why ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you have a variable `isBtnEnabled` and depending on whether it's true or not you want to display the `button`. If so this would be the better approach in your case:

```
{
   isBtnEnabled 
   && <button onClick={this.props.someDispatchedAction} />
}
```

If you want to change the `event` handler you can just do something like this:

```
<button onClick={isBtnEnabled && this.props.someDispatchedAction }/>
```

However, if you just want to `disable`/`enable` the `button` check out @RamizWachtler answer

Or you can just do this:

```
<button onClick={this.props.someDispatchedAction} disabled={!isBtnEnabled}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the default `disabled` property? Something like this

```
const btnProps = {
    disabled: !isBtnEnabled
};

<button onClick={this.onButtonClick} {...btnProps}>
    Click me
</button>
```

Inside the `onButtonClick`

```
const {doSomething} = this.props;

doSomething();
```

> Which solution is better and why ?

I think this depends on your personal preferences or the internal agreements within the team. In my opinion it's cleaner to separate the onClick methods from the render method.